# How to perform some action when app is closed by sending push notification in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I don't know whether i have to ask this question here or not, but i am really confused how to perform such thing.

I have to send sms via iphone, as i will receive push notification.

If my App is in foreground or in background i know how to do this, but if app is closed ie. not active then how i can perform such thing.

I don't want to prompt any message or alert.I just want to make it simple, As i send any message via push notification, my app receive it and perform the needful.

i can seen the api UIApplicationStateInactive. Is this api detect when app is closed, as after closing app i can't debug i don't know how it works.

If it is possible, please guide me how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible AFAIK.

User need to interact with your app for performing some tasks when a notification is arrived. Else you can't do anything in a closed app.

Comment: As in Android this is possible, so i asked.Thanks for reply.

Comment: Is it possible to launch app automatically when it receive push notification.

Comment: @Sawant: It's ok, also sending message without user permission (user interaction) is illegal in iOS. If you do so, your app will be rejected.

Comment: @Sawant - ya it is possible. You can launch your app as notification has recieved, by clicking on that notification.

Comment: @Sawant: No, user need to tap on the notification alert or badge for opening the app. It can't be launch automatically.

Comment: @Midhun I appreciate the privacy policy of apple.As for push notification or location service or photo access it ask for the permission very first time. Is there any similar way to do the same.

Comment: @Sawant: for sending sms ? No. User need to initiate for sending SMS.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to use web services to send the sms when user get the push notification .
Once i used same

Comment: I think you have not understand my requirement.

Comment: @Sawant .. Actually if you want to send the sms from Phone then it is not possible in in active application..

Answer (score 0):

your app will not active **application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:** is not working,when the app will launch from **application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** that time we manually check
notification like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 UILocalNotification *localNotif =[launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {

         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Sandeep Sharma` as suggested , you can use `WebService` to do as you wish.

Otherwise there is no any way to like that , because user must interact with your app to that thing.

You can launch your app as  notification has arrived and can send the SMS after app has opened.